# Java Swing - Disappearing text in custom combobox renderer in Motif L&F

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listcellrenderer, motif

I'm currently writing a custom `ListCellRenderer` for a `JComboBox`. To do this, I'm using a system to fetch a new renderer whenever the L&F changes, and delegate the method to this. This works nicely in all L&Fs. However, when I place this component in a panel (so I can add some more components), it works nicely in the Metal and Windows L&Fs, but the `JComboBox` text disappears in Motif. See screenshot and code:

[image: Problem with the third renderer]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static JFrame frame;

    public TextDemo() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        JComboBox correct = new JComboBox(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});

        JComboBox alsoCorrect = new JComboBox(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
        alsoCorrect.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());

        JComboBox incorrect = new JComboBox(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
        incorrect.setRenderer(new NotWorkingRenderer());

        JButton button = new JButton("Change LnF");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        add(correct, getConstraints(0));
        add(alsoCorrect, getConstraints(1));
        add(incorrect, getConstraints(2));
        add(button, getConstraints(3));
    }

    private GridBagConstraints getConstraints(int y) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0; c.gridy = y;
        c.insets = new Insets(4,8,4,8);
        c.weightx = 1.0; c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextDemo());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {
    protected static ListCellRenderer delegate;
    static {
        refreshRenderers();
        UIManager.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("lookAndFeel")) {
                    refreshRenderers();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    protected static void refreshRenderers() {
        delegate = new JComboBox().getRenderer();
    }
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        return delegate.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value,
                index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }
}

class NotWorkingRenderer extends MyRenderer {
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    public NotWorkingRenderer() {
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    }
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        c.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
                    panel.removeAll();
        panel.add(c);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Any help on understanding why this happens would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not an answer,

- but see whats happens, with JPanel as renderers JComponents for JComboBox
- are you sure that JPanel with String value is proper way, please whats goal,
- is there the same effect with default JLabel, (J)Component instead of JPanel

[image][image][image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static JFrame frame;

    public TextDemo() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());
        JComboBox correct = new JComboBox(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
        JComboBox alsoCorrect = new JComboBox(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
        alsoCorrect.setRenderer(new MyRenderer());
        JComboBox incorrect = new JComboBox(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
        incorrect.setRenderer(new NotWorkingRenderer());
        JButton button = new JButton("Change LnF");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(incorrect, getConstraints(0));
        add(correct, getConstraints(1));
        add(alsoCorrect, getConstraints(2));
        add(button, getConstraints(3));
    }

    private GridBagConstraints getConstraints(int y) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = y;
        c.insets = new Insets(4, 8, 4, 8);
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TextDemo());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel");
            //SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

    protected static ListCellRenderer delegate;

    static {
        refreshRenderers();
        UIManager.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("lookAndFeel")) {
                    refreshRenderers();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected static void refreshRenderers() {
        delegate = new JComboBox().getRenderer();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        return delegate.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value,
                index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }
}

class NotWorkingRenderer extends MyRenderer {

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public NotWorkingRenderer() {
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        c.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        panel.add(c);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

EDIT_1st.

- all Standard L&F excluding ModifL&F showing that properly
- one step forward ???, code line `incorrect.setEditable(true);` generating

[image]

- I'm don't know proper way for ModifL&F and non_editable JComboBox

EDIT_2nd.

- I'm blind `class NotWorkingRenderer extends MyRenderer {`, pip... pip... pip...
- phaaa I'm participated on never ever to `add` / `remove` / `modify` a `JComponent` in `Xxx(Xxx)Renderer`, but is about if is possible or not,

[image]

```
class NotWorkingRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public NotWorkingRenderer() {
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        //panel.setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JLabel c = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        c.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE));        
        panel.removeAll();
        panel.add(c);
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my code to fix a minor bug (forgot to clear the panel each time). The goal is to add an icon to the left of the gotten component, with a JLabel. So I want to add, to the panel, a JLabel, and then the retrieved delegate component c.

Comment: by default Renderer isn't proper place for add, remove, modify JComponent stored, came from XxxModel, works with incorrect.setEditable(true); but I'm not able to force non_editable JComboBox to showing rendering context, forgot about Opacity or getEditor from JComboBox

Comment: Thanks for your testing though, it may help riddling this out! :)

Comment: see how is this *** *** *** and  possible

Comment: Thanks mKorbel, the problem somehow has to do with the extending and delegation. Maybe there is a component setting which is reset when you delegate. I can figure it out from here, thanks!

Comment: someone will crucify me for this answer, +1 you are welcome for quite good lesson for me,

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the `panel` instead of `c`

```
Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        c.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
                    panel.removeAll();
        panel.add(c);
        return c;
```

Comment: The whole idea is to return the panel, since I might want to add other components (like icons, labels etc) to it.